netdata agent does not visualise the chart
Good afternoon. I am new to netdata, so I may still be confused about the terminology.
on my production server, the netdata agent is already running and collecting data, visualisation is working, including correct display of mysql plugins, etc.
But now I need to have a chart created for freeradius.
I used the documentation for installing the plugin - https://www.netdata.cloud/integrations/data-collection/authentication-and-authorization/freeradius/ - and it doesn't work (:

Here is what I have:
cat /etc/netdata/go.d.conf
modules:
  example: no
  prometheus: no
  k8s_state: no
  k8s_kubeproxy: no
  k8s_kubelet: no
  nginx: yes
  mysql: yes
  postgres: yes
  supervisord: yes
  freeradius: yes
  phpfpm: yes
  redis: yes
  openvpn: yes

Status work in freeradius:
server status {
        listen {
                #  ONLY Status-Server is allowed to this port.
                #  ALL other packets are ignored.
                type = status

                ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
                port = 18121
        }
....
        client admin {
                ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
                secret = adminsecret
        }
...

/var/log/netdata# journalctl _SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID="$(systemctl show --value --property=InvocationID netdata)" --namespace=netdata --grep free
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --

freeradius.conf the correct permissions set
/etc/netdata/go.d# ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  2 netdata netdata 4096 Aug 14 23:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root    root    4096 Aug 14 18:38 ..
-rw-r-----  1 netdata netdata   88 Aug 14 23:52 freeradius.conf
-rw-r-----  1 netdata netdata   93 Feb 21  2023 mysql.conf
-rw-r-----  1 netdata netdata   68 Feb 21  2023 nginx.conf
-rw-r-----  1 netdata netdata   54 Feb 21  2023 openvpn.conf
-rw-r-----  1 netdata netdata  110 Feb 21  2023 phpfpm.conf
-rw-r-----  1 netdata netdata   90 Feb 21  2023 postgres.conf
-rw-r-----  1 netdata netdata    9 Feb 21  2023 redis.conf
-rw-r-----  1 netdata netdata  117 Feb 21  2023 supervisord.conf

